# How to predict new data goes which cluser in R

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, predict

I already have k means output and i have segmented my users accordingly. Now, I have to predict cluster number for new users whenever they come. Do I have to run kmeans each time a new user comes into the picture or is there any easy way like using predict function. Please let me know if there is any ready example for this. Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which cluster do the new data belongs to after finishing cluster analysis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567801/how-to-know-which-cluster-do-the-new-data-belongs-to-after-finishing-cluster-ana)

Comment: Also, please **do not cross-post**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/204512/7828 and use the search function to find related questions first. We already have many duplicates of this question...

Answer (score 0):

Each cluster has a corresponding [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Centroid-based_clustering). When a new datapoint arrives, you can just assign to the cluster corresponding to the centroid that is closest to the new point.

Alternatively, you can instead do another step of the `k`-means algorithm, but *you don't have to run it from scratch*.

Perhaps more importantly, is there a bound on the number of users that can enter? If the number (of new users that may enter) is large enough to *change* the clusters (so that what you have computed is no longer valid), then you might want to consider [data stream clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_stream_clustering).

Comment: Thanks blaz. How to run only a step of kmeans? sorry this might be easy one but i am new in R.

Comment: @Sagar, that depends on the R package that you're using.

Comment: @Sagar, can you specify the R package that you're using? :-) So that I can read the documentation to see how to get centroids, do a single k-means step, etc.

Comment: @ Blaz, I am using R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

Comment: Yes, but what _package_? Maybe you just copy and paste the relevant code?

Comment: @ Blaz, can you please help me with how to find my package name for kmeans

Comment: @Sagar, yes, but I can only do that if I see the code. You probably imported the package using `library(packageName)` in R. Can you list all `packageName`'s ?

Comment: [Package stats version 3.2.3 ]
I have used "stats" Package